# Как подготовить сайт к размещению?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, веб-сайт

Я учусь и наступил тот момент, когда хочу загрузить сайт (html+css+js) в сеть. Понятно, что сначала надо оплатить хостинг, домен. Но увидел информацию про какие-то FTP и прочее. Был бы очень благодарен, если бы дали инструкции (или видео) к любой популярной хостинг-площадке

Comment: Никакие FTP не надо. Всё что надо - добыть/поднять веб-сервер и сделать его доступным извне. Можно даже на своём домашнем компьютере без всяких хостингов и доменов - это всё мелочи

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если сайт учебный, то для начала стоит воспользоваться бесплатными хостингами. Пользовался двумя:

1. [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)  Для несложных сайтов без `php`. По-моему js поддерживается.

Как пользоваться:

1. Регистрируемся на [GitHub](https://github.com/).
2. Создаем Публичный репозиторий, куда закидываем файлы сайта. Для этого удобно использовать [github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) Как пользоваться им читаем [тут](https://o7planning.org/ru/10283/using-github-with-github-desktop)
3. Идем в раздел Settings нашего репозитория на сайте Github
4. Находим пункт github Pages и выбираем основную ветку репозитория master
5. Переходим по ссылке и радуемся.

И второй хостинг [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/) Я пользуюсь так:

1. Регистрируемся и создаем новый проект.
2. Выбираем сервер США или Европа.
3. Подключаем репозиторий с гитхаба Во вкладке deploy.
4. Тыкаем по кнопке deploy Breach
5. Видим сайт. Радуемся.

На втором можно запускать любые файлы, в том числе php. Видео по обоим глянуть можно на ютубе, но там все интуитивно понятно, а если знаете английский, так вообще легко разобраться. Если надо добавлю скрины.

P. S. Вот отличная [видео-инструкция к github pages и хостингам](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84cyW2R9WWo&ab_channel=%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-IT%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81)